# How To Use CSS3 For Smooth Parallax Scrolling Cross-Browser, Cross-Platform

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, transform, parallax

I'm implementing a parallax header on a page. It works pretty well with the Apple TrackPad on Firefox & Safari on Mac OS X. But doesn't work so well on Chrome for Mac nor on any browser in Windows.

This is the jQuery I'm implementing:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
 * PARALLAX HEADER IMAGE
\*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$(window).scroll( function(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
  slowScroll = scroll*.85;
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    $('.no-touch  .js--parallax-header').css({ transition: "" });
  }, 50));
  $('.no-touch  .js--parallax-header').css({
    transform: "translate3d( 0, " + slowScroll + "px, 0)",
    transition: "none" });
});
```

[This is the page](http:////development.infowest.com/infowest/contact) I'm trying to implement it on.

It's jittery for one. And with a mouse with a scroll wheel, it's very jumpy. My page does also have a transform effect on it for an off canvas navigation menu so I think I need to work around that.

[Squarespace does an excellent job](http:////developers.squarespace.com) of implementing this same parallax effect. How did they do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: First, you should add functionality to html and body: $("html, body").scroll...
Second, I don't know why you are overwriting jquery's animation, but you could just use it.
Third, you could use translate3d but isn't it much simple to use translateY as you only want to move vertically?
And forth, for mobile phones and some devices, jquery's performance is pretty bad, I'd recomend you using a pure js solution or avoiding the parallax on mobile.

Comment: The title of your question seems incorrect. Aren't you actually asking "How To Use jQuery For Smooth Parallax..."? Also, the Squarespace home page does not contain a parallax anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Based on how SquareSpace did it:

1. The background image is separate from content. See `div.fullscreen-background-image` and `section.hero-text`
2. This allows `section.hero-text` to be part of the normal scroll
3. On scroll, they change the `transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` of the image inside `div.fullscreen-background-image` which is good because `transform` is considered a [high performance animation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)!
4. Without digging to deep into their `js`, I'd assume they `debounced` the scroll event and used `requestAnimationFrame()`. [Read more about that here!](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/)

That all being said, you don't have a lot of content to scroll over the lady, so why not consider adding her to the `body` as a `background-image` and making her `background-attachment: fixed;` so that the page scrolls over her? [Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).